# Can I create multiple channels within an organisation in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am setting up a single organization Hyperledger Fabric network.I want to create multiple channels within the organization and restrict access to channels? i.e., peerA has access only on channelA and peerB has access only on channelB

Can I get some insight on how to create different channels on different peers of the organisations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain clearly,

Hyperledger fabric is a consortium oriented

Consortium is the high-level and channel, organizations are subset of consortium , which means one consortium contains channels and organizations

one channel can have multiple organizations

organizations participate in the channel by joining their peers

Each channel has a separate ledger

Coming to your **question**

```
peerA has access only on channelA and peerB has access only on channelB
```

join peerA of org1 to only channelA
join peerB of org1 to only channelB

```
Can I create multiple channels within the organization and restrict access to channels?
```

YES, you can create as no of channel you want

below I presented the configtx with two channels

```
Organizations:
  - &org1
    Name: org1
    ID: org1MSP
    MSPDir: ./data/orgs/org1/msp
    AnchorPeers:
      - Host: org1-peer-org1
      - Port: 7051
  - &org2
    Name: org2
    ID: org2MSP
    MSPDir: ./data/orgs/org2/msp
    AnchorPeers:
      - Host: org2-peer-org2
      - Port: 7051


Capabilities:
    Global: &ChannelCapabilities
        V1_3: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V1_1: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V1_3: true
        V1_2: false
        V1_1: false


Application: &ApplicationDefaults
  Organizations:


Profiles:
  OrgsOrdererGenesis:
    Capabilities:
      <<: *ChannelCapabilities
    Orderer:
      OrdererType: kafka
      Addresses:
        - org1-orderer-org1:7050
        - org2-orderer-org2:7050
      BatchTimeout: 2s
      BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 56
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 34 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 4354 KB
      Kafka:
        Brokers:
          - kafka0:9092
          - kafka1:9092
          - kafka2:9092
      Organizations:
        - *org1
        - *org2
      Capabilities:
        <<: *OrdererCapabilities
    Consortiums:
      transport:
        Organizations:
          - *org1
          - *org2

  OrgsChannel1:
    Consortium: transport
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *org1
        - *org2
      Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

  OrgsChannel2:
    Consortium: transport
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *org1
      Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Comment: can i create a channel after the network is running and chaincode is instantiated?

Comment: should I use the same method, If i want an org to join multiple channel?